# Can not see changes in json file in java project (jsp)

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, d3.js

I an using intellij IDEA to make a web project with a jsp. I get my data from "customer.json" file and when click a button I change this "customer.json" file in backend.Then I try to get the data again but it reads old json file. I tried to disable caching with following code:

```
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
  response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
  response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxyserver
```

I also tried add new json file with different name like "customer_1.jsp" and read it from my jsp but this time I got error which says that there is no such file named "customer_1.jsp" even I see it in the directory. What is the problem and how can I solve it ? Thanks for any help?

Note: I am using the data for d3.js and I read it with following code:

```
d3.json("{path}/customer.json", function(error, json) {
   if (error) return console.warn(error);
   data = json;
   visualizeit();
});
```

Note: I am writing here also mu click event with coffescript version.(It is easy to understand):

```
 $(".node").live "dblclick",(e) ->
    selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
    loadData(selectedId)
    setTimeout(updateForSelected(selectedId),5000)

  loadData = (selectedId) ->
    $("#waitForUpdating").load 'DataForSelectedCustomer.jsp?id='+selectedId;

  updateForSelected = (selectedId) ->
    d3.json "customer.json", (json) ->
      myNetwork.updateData(json)
```

And in "DataForSelectedCustomer.jsp" I call the Java function that writes to json file.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what do you mean by refreshing IDE directory. It is user interactive project and any time a user click it should I change the whole directory?

Comment: yes sorry , was thinking something else

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `customer.json` file is downloaded by your browser, and it will always use the local copy. If you want to refresh the file, you have to fetch it from your backend again using [JQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

1. the browser downloads the files to display the web page
2. you change the JSON file in the back-end, wich is not readable by the browser
3. you download the new JSON file and use that in the front-end again

Comment: I updated my question. I think I made Ajax call using this load function. But still it reads old json. And sorry, I could not understand what do  you mean by download the new Json?Does not d3.json("customer.json") it do it already ?

Comment: Yes you would say d3 does that already, I don't have experience with d3 but it seems to me that the library fetches the JSON document once, and then uses the local cached file. That's why I think you need to fetch it again if you want to see the updates.

Comment: I tried $.getJSON( "customer.json",( json ) ->newJsonx = json then alert newJsonx but it always give the same result.

Comment: I look chrome's Network section. It shows that customerç.json not modified. However it does. Can it be related with browser? If so what can I do to fix it ?